# Response.Redirect Broken for External Links

Tags: asp.net, redirect, response.redirect

When using IIS8 (ARR too, if that matters) and we run something simple such as

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com/news");
```

The redirection will strip the domain from the redirect.
It will attempt to redirect to /news (as if it were a relative URL)

This does not happen on IIS Express when running on a local dev machine.

Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I just tried this on Server 2012 R2, absolutely no problem.

Comment: We are running 2012... it is happening every time for us.  It has to either be a bug or a known issue, but we see it happening for sure.

Comment: any special settings in IIS? where did you put this code? In code behind file?

Comment: No special IIS... only ARR running in front as this is part of a farm.  To test this out, we literally created a single page aspx file and placed the redirect in the Page_Load event.

The reason this even came up was that we had some production code that quit working. In an effort to troubleshoot, we just made a single page file (no code behind even) and observed what happened.

Comment: We do believe this is probably ARR related at the heart... just not sure how...

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to look at the request/response - sometimes it can be very illuminating as to what's actually happening. You can download it for free here http://fiddler2.com/